# Any way to modify an already existing rig for a character?

Tags: rigging

A model I'm using already came pre-rigged and was ripped directly from a game. I'm able to work with it, but there's just a lot of controls that are positioned oddly (sticking out rather than inside the actual model). I'd already attempted to fully re-rig the model but ended up with parts that stuck out everywhere. [image]

Is there any way in which I could simply move the armatures without it affecting the model/parenting/etc.?

Comment: What format is the imported model? The FBX importer has options that can control the bone orientation (in the right panel, the "Armature" section at the bottom). If the model was ripped from a game then the armature has only deformation bones but no control bones (IK/FK, constraints, etc) that make animation easier. You can add your own control bones and add *Copy...* bone constraints so that you can pose the deformation bones with the new control bones (retarget). Alternatively, you can rig the model from scratch, including weight painting.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late response :) The file was indeed an FBX model. How exactly could I add control bones? Sorry, I'm a little new to everything!